# Kernel debugging - vmlinux-gdb.py fails to run on gdb

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to remotely-debug a Linux's kernel.
I've created a VM (using VMware) and connected to it from my PC using gdb, and everything works fine.

The problem is that gdb fails to load vmlinux-gdb.py script. I've tried to add it using the `source` command on gdb, and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/workspace/kernels/default-kernel/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py", line 28, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'linux'
```

The directory tree:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 iofek iofek 4096 Mar 22 19:59 linux
-rwxr-xr-x  1 iofek iofek  577 Mar 22 19:43 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x  1 iofek iofek    0 Mar 22 19:43 modules.order
-rwxr-xr-x  1 iofek iofek  759 Mar 22 20:00 vmlinux-gdb.py
```

Now I can't understand why the module fails to find the linux directory.
I've updated the PYTHONPATH, as well as added the path using `sys.path.append`.
Additionaly, all files under linux has the right permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of the gdb command `python os.system("ls " + sys.path[-1] + "/linux/__init__.py")`, where `-1` is the appropriate subscript to get the path you appended to  `sys.path` ?

Comment: It prints the whole path since it exists....

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Never use ...linux.../scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py.Use the file vmlinux-gdb.py that is in the root directory of your kernel build output, alongside your vmlinux file.

If this file does not exist, you need to:

```
Activate CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS in your kernel configuration
```

## Long tutorial

First make sure the gdb-scripts will be created during the kernel build:

```
make menuconfig
Enable CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS
make
```

Then find out if your kernel build is using a separate build output folder and then follow ONE (xor) of the following chapters:

### Either: Building in-place without a build binary dir

If you compile your kernel with .o and .ko files cluttered inside the source (which is e.g. the way Ubuntu recommends it on [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)) you can cd into the source root folder, let's for example assume you built in the folder ~/gdbenv, start gdb from there and then loading should be possible out-of-the-box:

```
cd ~/gdbenv
gdb ./vmlinux
(gdb) add-auto-load-safe-path ~/gdbenv
(gdb) source ~/gdbenv/vmlinux-gdb.py
```

### Or: When your way of building a kernel outputs binaries in a separate build dir

Which is done e.g. in a Yocto build, where all binaries end up in a different folder, not mixed with the source folder. In such environments you need to grab everything together in one environment (vmlinux, gdb-scripts and optionally the kernel sources).

```
tar -xf ~/Downloads/linux-blabla.tgz -C ~/gdbenv       (optional)
cp .../build/vmlinux-gdb.py ~/gdbenv
mkdir ~/gdbenv/scripts
cp -r .../build/scripts/gdb ~/gdbenv/scripts
cp .../build/vmlinux ~/gdbenv

Then procede like in the preceeding chapter (cd ~/gdbenv, gdb ./vmlinux ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

For latest kernels, you need build gdb scripts:

<root of kernel source>: **make scripts_gdb**

After making, a symlink of vmlinux-gdb.py will be created at the root of kernel source. Then:

<root of kernel source>: **gdb vmlinux**

<gdb cmd>: **add-auto-load-safe-path root-of-kernel-source**

<gdb cmd:> **source vmlinux-gdb.py**